# IBM Content Navigator customization

Tags: ecm, ibm-content-navigator

Is there any technical tutorial on the net for customizing the Filenet Content Navigator except the tutorial from RedBooks?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v5r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.developingeuc.doc%2Feucdi000.htm) topic?

Answer (score 6):

There's the redbook and in case you missed it, you can get the plugins and source code from the book right here:
[Redbook source code (10 projects)](ftp://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG248055/SG248055.zip)

It should be enough to learn how to make a plugin yourself after going through all the code.

Answer (score 5):

The Redbook for customizing ICN is the only published resource for ICN currently.  Throughout my customization work, I've found the [ICN forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002869) on DeveloperWorks to be invaluable.

Comment: The ICN Forum url you referred in your answer appears to be broken. Does anyone have the updated URL?

Answer (score 1):

Also you might be interested by [Not Only An ECM Place](http://notonlyanecmplace.com).